# Haskell on iOS with current xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, haskell, ghc

I am having trouble getting Haskell up and running on iOS using the GHC-ios github projects.

What is the most reliable method to get GHC configured with xcode for ios?

Comment: Check [this link](http://gergo.erdi.hu/blog/2011-02-13-developing_iphone_applications_in_haskell___a_tutorial/) , you will get some idea